# List all gradle dependencies with their licences

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, gradle, intellij-plugin

I want to list all maven dependencies (including transitive ones) of my gradle build with their licenses. Is this possible with the IntelliJ gradle plugin? If yes, how? Alternatively a gradle command line  instruction would be sufficient, too.

Comment: No idea if license info is stored in gradle. You probably need to dig into source code or do some debugging.

Comment: Not in gradle but in maven. The projects includes maven dependencies with gradle.

Comment: Yes, I understood. But You need to display the data using gradle, yes?

Comment: Yes, because the dependencies are set in the build.gradle file. I want the process to take every dependency, search for all transitive dependencies, and list all of them including their licenses. In worst case it would be enough to only see all dependencies and search the licenses by hand.

Comment: Is running `gradle dependencies` what You are looking for?

Comment: Ah, didn't used gradle yet via command line. The list of dependencies helps very much. Still, the licenses are missing. Maybe their is a parameter to show them?

Comment: No rather not. Will investigate this later, maybe will find a way to help.

Comment: I found a plugin that may help: https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin . One of its features states: "This plugin will also report on the licenses of your dependencies."

Comment: Yes, should be what You're looking for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would recommend the [license-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin). It can report on licenses from your dependencies via the downloadLicense task.

Comment: Yes, it's a great tool. Could you please extend your answer how to set the properties properly? I don't know where to do the following: downloadLicenses { 
 includeProjectDependencies = true 
 dependencyConfiguration = 'compile'
}
Should that be part of the build.gradle file?

Comment: Ok, found it myself. It has to be in the build.gradle. But I was not searching for compile but providedCompile :)

Comment: How to generate the report though? ./gradlew buildLicenses DOES NOT do anything for me

Comment: I'm having trouble with it on an Android project. The report is empty.

Comment: Same to me as my report is empty too...

Comment: The same for me, report is empty

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work with gradle 7 and the project has not been updated recently

Answer (score 10):

For anybody who ends up here and discovered the license-gradle-plugin appears to be unmaintained, [Gradle-License-Report](https://github.com/jk1/Gradle-License-Report) works for this need as well.

Comment: This project seems to be maintained and the `license-gradle-plugin` doesn't seem to work for my 7.4 Gradle project, whereas `Gradle-License-Report` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The only plugin that has worked for my **Android** project is **Gradle License Plugin**
https://github.com/jaredsburrows/gradle-license-plugin

The setup was quite simple - just one line in the project-level build.gradle and another line in the app-level build.gradle. My project is relatively complex, but doesn't have multiple modules btw.

P.S. I've also tried https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin and https://github.com/jk1/Gradle-License-Report with no success.

Comment: This was the only one working for me as well. Others generated empty files. I had some trouble setting up, but that was because I was applying the plugin in the project-level build.gradle, and apparently it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries
It covers the Kotlin Multiplatform as well.
Actually it covers any gradle type projects.